# Update events from recurring event of Google Calendar using C# API

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, recurring-events

I am using the C# Google API to add the Recurring Events programmatically from my application(asp.net mvc - C#). Following is the code for it( I am adding a Daily Event which starts on Dec 01, 2012 and ends at Dec 03, 2012):

```
GOAuthRequestFactory authFactory = new GOAuthRequestFactory("cl", "MyApp");
authFactory.ConsumerKey = "xxxx";
authFactory.ConsumerSecret = "yyyy";
authFactory.Token = "zzzz";
authFactory.TokenSecret = "ssss";
Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService service = new Google.GData.Calendar.CalendarService(authFactory.ApplicationName);
service.RequestFactory = authFactory;

EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();
entry.Title.Text = "Year End Meeting";

Recurrence recur = new Recurrence();
recur.Value = "DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20121201\r\nDTEND;VALUE=DATE:20121201\r\nRRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20121203;INTERVAL=1";
entry.Recurrence = recur;

Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");
EventEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry);
if (insertedEntry != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(insertedEntry.EventId))
{
   //Update the Google Event Id to the Event Table
    this.UpdateGoogleEventId(_userId, _eventId, insertedEntry.EventId);
}
```

Until this everything goes fine. Now i need to update a particular Event(only this instance) from the Recurring Event. For Ex.; I need to change the Dec 02, 2012 Event's Title to "Plan for Next Year". Likewise, I need to do the same for All Following, All events in this series update actions also. I was doing a Delete of all Events based on the Google Event Id(which is in the response when creating the Recurring Event) and then again creating the Events, which is kind of double work.

This is how i delete all the Recurring Events and do the Create as given above:

```
Uri delteUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/" + googleeventid);
EventQuery deleteQuery = new EventQuery(delteUri.ToString());
EventFeed deleteFeed = service.Query(deleteQuery);
if (deleteFeed.Entries.Count > 0)
{
   AtomEntry eve = deleteFeed.Entries[0];
   if (eve != null)
   {
       service.Delete(eve);
   }
}
```

What is the best way to just update only the instance based on the required conditions(Only this instance, All following, All events in this series)?

Comment: Just wondering, did you ever figure this out? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @MingSlogar, I still didn't get any solution. Keeping it as a known issue for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Just figured this out 10 minutes ago.

To access a single instance of a recurring event on a certain date use the following as the event url:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/" 
    + googleEventId + "_" + dateTime.ToString("yyyyMMdd");
```